# Cannot see preview of CorelDRAW files

Tags: windows-7, preview

I’m using Windows 7 and CorelDRAW 12.
For some reason, I cannot see previews of CorelDRAW files on my Desktop or in the drives - only the name and ‘white page' icon is displayed. In the past, I have been able to preview these files. Could anyone offer a suggestion as to how I can restore the preview?

[image]

[image]
[image: Image showing file without preview]

Comment: Reinstall/repair Corel Draw.

Comment: @DanielB yeah i have did that still the same

Comment: @miroxlav im really sorry i was attaching the file so i have reject from editing now your are free to edit

Comment: @atek – I suggest you making your questions more readable by using proper letter case, punctuation etc.  Please see revision #2 from another user (click *edited* link above) before you made revision #3. I'm letting you know because nearly all your questions suffer from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people over at CorelDraw Community got back the thumbnails by associating the file type to another program (Windows Image Viewer, but really anything) and that re-associating it with CorelDraw.

Answer (score 0):

Associate file with program

Typically you do not need to reinstall entire CorelDraw when experiencing this problem.

#### Reinstall `Corel Graphics - Windows Shell Extension`.

1. Uninstall it from control panel (in Programs and Features search for the above name).
2. Reinstall it from `C:\Program Files\Corel\Corel Draw Graphics Suite*\Setup\CGS*\ShellExt.exe`
    
   `*` in the above denotes omitted characters which vary by CGS version
    
   • If there is no setup folder, search for `ShellExt.exe` on installation media.
   • If you are able simply to reassociate CorelDraw with its file types, this could help even without reinstalling anything. But for many users, reinstallation can be easier.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfN9hz4fISw

#### Answer for CorelDRAW 12:

I cannot get relevant resources because the version is too old but you can try to reassociate CoreDRAW application with `CorelDraw 12 Graphic` file type. ([General how-to.](https://www.google.sk/search?q=windows%207%20associate%20file%20with%20program))

If this simple repair does not help, then reinstall. It could be faster than other possible tweaks.

Comment: As mention above after graphics suite \ setup folder does not exists screen shot attach above

Comment: There is no shellext.exe file i found i have search

Comment: I see. Corel Draw 12 was published in 2004 (13 years ago) so it is possible that it had quite different structure that time. So first, try to reassociate your `CorelDRAW 12.0 Graphic` file type with CorelDraw application manually. (Google "Associate file with program".) If this fails, then reinstall CorelDRAW. My answer was targetted for newer versions of CorelDRAW Suite.

Comment: But i mention above its coreldraw 12 not the never version

Comment: Sure. But I did not know that CorelDraw 12 could have different package structure from recent versions (e.g. from X7). It is more difficult to find resources for such old versions so therefore my advice is: reassociate or reinstall – it could be the easiest way in this case.